# ¿Como mandar llamar un procedimiento almacenado creado desde la base datos en ASP.NET MVC Core con Entity Framework Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedure, entity-framework-core

Que tal gente tengo algún tiempo que migré a mvc core, anteriormente utilizaba mvc 5.

Me surgió la siguiente espero puedan apoyarme a como resolverlo.

Estoy intentando hacer mostrar un SP de pruebas el cual está basado en una consulta a dos tablas (dos modelos) con la base de datos de Northwind.

```
--MOSTRAR VENTAS Y EMPLEADOS
create procedure sp_ventas_empleado
as 
begin 
    select e.FirstName + ' '+ e.LastName as nombre_completo, 
    count(o.OrderID) as ordenes_vendidas from Employees e 
    inner join Orders o
    on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    group by e.FirstName, e.LastName
end
```

Hice la conexión mediante el siguiente comando:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLDELL;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

o si necesito actualizar algo de las tablas agrego el comando `-Force`

y agregué lo siguiente en el startup.cs

```
   var connection = @"Server=.\SQLDELL;DataBase=BD_Asistencias; Trusted_Connection=True; ConnectRetryCount=0";
    services.AddDbContext<BD_AsistenciasContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Anteriormente en MVC 5 para imprimir un SP que involucre dos o mas tablas lo que hacia era ir directo al modelo y seleccionaba **actualizar modelo de base de datos** y posteriormente agregaba el Stored Procedure.

En el View en la seccion @model escribía literalmente el modelo

```
@model IEnumerable<mvc_SP.Models.sp_ventas_empleado_Result>
```

Y en el controlador algo como lo siguiente:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //conexion
        IEnumerable<sp_ventas_empleado_Result> llamada_sp;
        using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            //llamar filtrar todos
            llamada_sp = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_ventas_empleado_Result>
                ("exec sp_ventas_empleado").ToList();
        }
        return View(llamada_sp);
    }
```

La gran duda que tengo es, ¿Como haría eso con MVC Core con EF Core? ya que en esta versión ya no existe el model que se creaba en el EF 6.

¿Existe alguna manera de importar los Stored Procedures que tengo en la base de datos al proyecto, algo similar a lo que hice con la conexión por medio de Database First?.

De antemano agradezco la ayuda que brinden. Se que a lo mejor no son las mejores manera de programación pero lo tomaré en cuenta para seguir creciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente Scaffold-DbContext no importa los tipos de los procedimientos almacenados, lo que tienes que hacer es generar un Query Type, que serán entidades de lectura:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types

Ya que tengas configurada tu entidad de lectura basta con que mandes a llamar la entidad con y executes el query de las base:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Para tu caso digamos que creas el QueryType VentasEmpleado, lo registras en el contexto y los mandas a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
context.VentasEmpleado.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo. sp_ventas_empleado").ToList();
```

Comment: Exactamente así fue, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como lo siguiente:

Asumiendo que tenemos este SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateStudent
    @FirstName Varchar(50),
    @LastName Varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert into Students(
           [FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
           )
 Values (@FirstName, @LastName)
END
GO
```

Lo ejecutariamos como sigue:

```
var context = new SchoolContext(); 

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CreateStudents @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { "Bill", "Gates" });
```